# Insert pch symbols on x-axis labels

Tags: r

```
par(mar=c(5,5,2,5), xpd=TRUE)

x <- seq(0,5,0.5)
y <- seq(0,5,0.5)
plot(x,y, xlab="", ylab="")
```

Is there a way to replace the x-axis labels (0,1,2,3,4,5) with symbols pch=2,pch=4,pch=6,pch=8,pch=10,pch=12?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fairly manual solution, but that's often what you get with base graphics:

```
par(mar=c(5,5,2,5), xpd=TRUE)

x <- seq(0,5,0.5)
y <- seq(0,5,0.5)
plot(x,y, xlab="", ylab="",xaxt = "n")
axis(side = 1,at = 0:5,labels = FALSE)
points(x = 0:5,y = rep(-0.5,6),pch = c(2,4,6,8,10,12))
```

[image]

Comment: Great! Is there a way to get both the numeric index and the symbol. For instance: 0 (pch=2), 1(pch=3), etc.

Comment: @user3639557 You mean label the ticks with both the integers and the symbols? I'd just drop the axis suppression bits, so it plots the x axis normally, and then shift the positions in the `points()` call either down or to the side.

Comment: I faced a problem using this.  It seems to allow stuff to fly over the plot margin. For instance, if you replace plot(x,y, xlab="", ylab="",xaxt = "n") with plot(x,y, xlab="", ylab="",xaxt = "n",panel.first={grid(20,20, lty =5, lwd=1, col = "grey90")}) the gird will run over the margins:

Comment: @user3639557 It's doing that only because you've changed the margin sizes for the plot.

Comment: @user3639557 I think maybe you want `xpd = FALSE` in this case.